# How to iterate json data with react js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

Here, i've included the html code for my webpage. Each category having the different kind of data items and structure. It will iterate data from json objects. How to fetch data from json api and how to implement this one with react js? I'm struggling to find the solution.

```
<div class="main">

      <div class="type-one">
        <div class="type-list">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="img/sample.png" alt="" width="143" />
            <h2>Lorem iplsum</h2>
            <div className="total-items">2 items</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="list">Item1</div>
            <div class="list">Item2</div>
            <div class="list">Item3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="type-list">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="img/sample.png" alt="" width="143" />
            <h2>Lorem iplsum</h2>
            <div className="total-items">2 items</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="list">Item1</div>
            <div class="list">Item2</div>
            <div class="list">Item3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="message">
        <p>Lorem ipsum doler sit amet.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="type-two">
        <div class="type-list">
          <div class="front">
            <img src="img/sample.png" alt="" width="143" />
            <h2>Lorem iplsum</h2>
            <div className="total-items">2 items</div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
            <div class="list">Item1</div>
            <div class="list">Item2</div>
            <div class="list">Item3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the code, i have tried so far.

```
var Category = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var list = this.props.data.map(function(el, i) {
            return  <div className="type-list" key={i}>
                      <div className="front">
                        <img src={el.category_img} alt="" />
                        <h2>{el.category_name}</h2>
                        <div className="total-items">{el.total_items} items</div>
                      </div>
                </div>;
        });

        return <div className="type-one">{ list }</div>;
    }
});

var data = [
    {
        category_name:"Lorem iplsum",
        total_items:2,
        category_img:"img/sample.png",
        sub:[
            {
                item_name:"item1"
            },
            {
                item_name:"item2"
            },
            {
                item_name:"item3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        category_name:"Lorem iplsum2",
        total_items:3,
        category_img:"img/sample.png",
        sub:[
            {
                item_name:"item21"
            },
            {
                item_name:"item22"
            },
            {
                item_name:"item23"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var Cover = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Category data={data}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: @DERIIIFranz. I have updated the code. But, here i have implemented only one category.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend to use jQuery's `ajax` therefore: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

use it like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "path/to/api"
}).done(function(data) {
  this.setState({data: data})
});
```

implement this pattern within your component's `componentWillMount()` and you'll be fine!